# Read a File From Cache, But Without Polluting the Cache (in Windows)

Tags: winapi, caching, file-io

Windows has a `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` flag that allows you to specify whether or not you want your I/O to be cached by the file system.

That's fine, but what if I want to *use* the cache if possible, but avoid modifying it?

In other words, how do you tell Windows the following?

> Read this file from the cache if it's already cached, but my data doesn't exhibit locality, so **do not put it into the cache**!

The SCSI standard defines a [Disable Page Out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCSI_Read_Commands#Read_.2810.29) bit that does precisely this, so I'm wondering how (if at all) it is possible to use that feature from Windows (with cooperation of the file system cache too, of course)?

---

**Edit: TL;DR:**

*What's the equivalent of `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH` for **reads**?*

Comment: To clarify, you want read to use cache if possible, but you don't want the results of read to be cached (presumably to avoid pre-empting more useful data)?

Comment: @Heandel: The purpose is exactly what @Phil said: to prevent *other* data from being kicked out of the cache when there's no need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two flags that look suspiciously like what you are asking for:

```
FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS
FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN
```

The later's doc clearly suggests that it won't retain pages in cache, though it will probably read-ahead sequentially. The former's doc is completely opaque, but would seem to imply what you want. If the pattern is quite random, hanging onto pages for later reuse would be a waste of memory.

Keep in mind that, for files, the Windows kernel always will use some pages of 'cache' to hold the I/O. It has nowhere else to put it. So it's not meaningful to say 'don't cache it,' as opposed to 'evict the old pages of this file before evicting some other pages.'

Comment: Those don't *quite* do what I'm asking for. They concern read-ahead behavior rather than caching behavior -- the former specifies that read-aheads are discouraged, and the latter specifies that they're encouraged, but neither says anything about evicting pages from the cache.

Comment: The language says that they are supposed to optimize your case. They don't say that they *do* what you want with memory, and they don't quite say that they *don't*. Absent comments from a kernel developer, I'd experiment if I had your problem.

Comment: I've actually already tried it -- the issue is that it still evicts other pages from the cache (hence why my hard disk thrashes so much when I run a different program), whereas `FILE_NO_INTERMEDIATE_BUFFERING` doesn't affect other programs at all. But of course, the latter doesn't use the cache at all, hence my problem.

Comment: Oh well, so much for catching a useful weasel in the weasel-words.

Answer (score 1):

About the closest Windows provides to what you're asking is `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH`.

Comment: @Mehrdad: yes -- that's why I said it's the closest it provides, not that it's really what you want.